# biharmonic complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, harmonic-functions

Complex analysis texts typically discuss analytic functions whose real and imaginary components are harmonic and satisfy the Laplace equation, $\nabla^2 f = 0$.

I am working with a complex function whose real and imaginary components satisfy the biharmonic equation instead, i.e. $\nabla^4 f= 0$. Thus far I have not been able to find very many resources and was wondering if anyone could point me towards any good books or papers covering this topic.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to have a look at http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510636.pdf. Surely you already know that a biharmonic function is the real part of $\overline zf(z)+g(z)$ for some holomorphic functions $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @Jonas Thanks, I will take a look at it.